# Update statement not hitting the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm just starting with my Visual Studio 2010,wanted to create a website, I have 2 drop down lists and 4 textbox's from which user enters the data and database should be updated  but its not happening, grid view is just showing my initial values of database. Can you please help me get the desired result.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace AppForSis
{
    public partial class AppForSis : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(
               "Data Source=HOME-AA3742A183;Initial Catalog=master;"
               + "Integrated Security=True");
            myConn.Open();
            SqlCommand up = new SqlCommand(
                @"UPDATE 
                      [resource1] 
                  SET
                      [date_entered] = @d, 
                      [pass] = @p, 
                      [fail] = @f, 
                      [blocked] = @b  
                  WHERE  ([rname] = @r)  
                      AND ([mname] = @m)", 
                myConn);

            up.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", date.Text);
            up.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", pass.Text);
            up.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", fail.Text);
            up.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", blocked.Text);
            up.Parameters.AddWithValue("@r", resource.SelectedValue);
            up.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", module.SelectedValue);
            up.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConn.Close();

           GridView1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really working with the `master` database? This database should not be used to store user tables.

Comment: yes i'm working in master database only

Comment: Then pack your tables and move away to a dedicated database. The `master` is for Microsoft to add, delete, rename, etc... By the way what are the datatypes of your columns? (date_entered, fail and blocked are varchar/nvarchar columns?)

Comment: all are varchar and date_entered is date...

Comment: i have done in a new database only,but deleted it..for posting this code i have used master for posting here..will change the data base thanks

Comment: The `date_entered` is date, but you use AddWithValue passing a Text string, this should not work. If you look at your `resource1` table with Management Studio, do you see the added record? (I ask this to understand if you have a problem in inserting data or just a problem in visualizing existing data in your gridview as someone else says in its answer)

Comment: i'm not having a problem as u mentioned...my problem is that i'm not able to update my user entered values in the database.By the way what we have to use for date instead of AddWithvalue @Steve

Comment: You said that the datatype in the column date_entered is date, then AddWithValue should be fed with a date not with a string. (I suppose date.Text is a textbox). If your date.Text contains a valid date then use `Convert.ToDateTime(date.Text)` as value for AddWithValue. Also try to catch if the ExecuteNonQuery throws exceptions with a [Try/Catch handler](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebind the code in the Page Load but use if (!Page.IsPostBack) This means that you'll bind the Fresh state of the DB in the first load and then rebind the changes after the update. So then, you'll have to use GridView1.DataBind() at the end of your code in the Button_Click. Please approve this have solved your problem.

Comment: could u post an example code..it will b very helpful as i'm a newbie.reply much awaiting

Comment: Just put this in the Page Load if (!Page.IsPostBack) { GridView1.DataSource = "Your Source Here"; GridView1.DataBind();//Make sure this is included

Comment: when i try this ,i am getting "both data source and data bind are defined on grid view1 ,remove one definition"

Comment: You are binding the GridView twice, remove the bindings in the .aspx or in the client side coding.